# Froyo (Android 2.2) source code

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

Is the Froyo (Android 2.2) source code available? I've browsed the Android code repository using gitweb and haven't found an Android 2.2 tag or a froyo head.

Comment: Yes i downloaded the source code of Froyo. Just follow the instruction in this link: [Initializing a Build Environment](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link to older Android sources:

http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android

Comment: see 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/froyo-code-drop.html for some comment on the new changes